# Star operator in Krasnikov

Tags: general-relativity, topology

In Krasnikov's paper [Hyperfast interstellar travel in general relativity](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9511068), he introduces the $\star$ operator, which he describes as follow :

> Below we deal with two spacetimes $N_i \subset M_i$ related by an isometry $\phi : N_2 = \phi(N_1)$. To shorten notation we shall write sometimes $X_{(1)}$ for a subset $X \subset N_1$, and $X_{(2)}$ for $\phi(X)$. The notation $A \star B$ for points $A$, $B$ will mean that there exists a sequence $\{a_n\}$ : $$a_{n(i)} \to A,\ a_{n(j)} \to B.$$ Clearly if $A\in N_1$, then $A \star B \neq A$ means simply $B = \phi(A)$.

The $\star$ operator seems to be defined as a relation, where two points are related if the sequence converges to each point in separate spacetime (although even that is not especially clear), but it seems to be used both as a function giving out a value (here and elsewhere in the paper), as well as as a relation giving out a truth valuation (for instance the theorem "If $M_i$ are globally hyperbolic spacetimes diverging by $S$, then $F_1\star F_2$").

I assume that the definition means that if there's a sequence $a_n$ converging in the first spacetime to $A$, the image of that sequence will converge to $B$ (isometries preserve sequences).

Which one is it supposed to be, and if it is a function, what value is it actually supposed to spit out?

Answer (score 0):

Like you, I guess that it should actually be
$$a_{n(i)} \to A, \quad \phi(a_{n(j)}) \to B.$$

Is it in formulas like $A \star B \neq A$ that you think $\star$ is used as a function, parsing it as $(A \star B) \neq A$? I'm quite certain that what's meant is "$A \star B$ and $B \neq A$". When one writes $x R y S z$, where $R$, $S$ are relations, that normally means "$x R y$ and $y S z$". On the other hand, if $A \in N_1$ and $B \in N_2$, then isn't it clear that $B \neq A$? I'm also confused.